# String.Format with a string containing html

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, database, asp.net-web-api

I am working on an application that fetches email templates from a database and then sends them.

The template from the database has the body has html, how can I do a String.Format on this string? Currently I am getting an error saying the input string is not in the right format.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <style>
        .container {
            font-size: 0;
        }

            .container.p.span {
                /*font-size: 16px;**/
            }

        .titleTextSpan {
            color: white;
            width: inherit;
            height: inherit;
            font-family: sans-serif, Arial;
            font-size: 20px;
            display: table-cell;
            vertical-align: middle;
            text-align: left;
        }
    </style>
    <div class="container" style="width:700px;">
        <div style="display:inline-block;">
        </div>
        <div style="width:700px;height:44px; background:#36A6DE;display:table;">
            <span class="titleTextSpan">PRODUCT NAME</span>
        </div>
        <div style="font-size:10pt;margin-left:20px;font-family:Arial, sans-serif;color:#4D4C4C">
            <br />
            Dear {16},
            <br /><br />
            Thank you for your request for PRODUCT NAME, which is now with your organisation approver for authorisation.
            <br />
            Call details:
            <br />
            Call number: {17}
            <br />
            Organisation Approver: {22} {23}
            <br />
            <br />
            If you have any other questions please do not hesitate to contact us.<br />
            Please email <a href="EMAIL">EMAIL</a> or contact your local team lead.
            <br />
            <br />
            Kind Regards,
            <br />
            <br />
            Intelligence Point Administrator
        </div>
        <div style="margin-top:20px;width:700px;height:10px; background:#36A6DE;display:table;"></div>
        <div style="width:700px;height:20px; background:#F1F1F1;display:table;"></div>
        <div style="width:700px;height:50px;background:#15314D;text-align:center;display:table">
            <span style="font-size:9pt; vertical-align:middle;color:#36A6DE; font-family:Arial, sans-serif;display:table-cell;">
                We welcome your comments, feedback and suggestions
            </span>
        </div>
        <div style="font-size:10pt; vertical-align:middle;color:black; font-family:Arial, sans-serif;text-align:center;">
            <b>Email:</b><a href=""> </a> | <b>Website:</b> <a href=""></a>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It's kinda hard to answer without seeing at least one string...

Comment: Please share the string you want to format

Comment: atleast share the string which you want to format

Comment: Sorry, had to edit the string due to it being to long. Added now

Comment: @mattlad564 You see those curly braces? They are the problem. Please see the duplicate question I linked to earlier.

Comment: @AndrewMorton I guessed this however, as i need it to be a valid html string won't escaping the characters stop it from being valid?

Comment: `str = str.Replace("{16}", "Matt");`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to escape each `{` and `}` in your html with `{{` and `}}` as String.Format considers them to be placeholder and not your css rules. BTW you can use String.Replace to replace the values for any other field before actually using String.Format

Comment: Will this allow it to still be a valid piece of html when it is displayed?

Comment: you can use String.Format on this html string after you escape them. After the replacing the value in string you can use the HTML.

Comment: this advice is very confusing. why would they escape these two placeholders? IMO it is important that the format placeholders are not escaped, but have consecutive indices starting at zero. For example "call number" has index 17, but 16, 18, 19, ... do not exist in the template.

Comment: The {22} and {23} are indices. it is the css that is the issue. The indices are not all present due to the templates being able to be generated by anyone and inserted into the database so restarting the index for each one is not practical as the String.Format would need to be rewritten every time

Comment: @mattlad564 thanks for confirming about the indices , I noticed the CSS part only which looked like problem to me.

Comment: I see. you are exploiting the fact that `String.Format("{2}", "a", "b", "c");` is legal.

Comment: @Niladri I had a feeling it would be that but i just wasn't sure if the HTML would still work afterwards

Answer (score 0):

basically, the problem here is the css part in the template. because of those curl braces. Having two tables for this template will be cleanest approach.
One table for style and another for pure html.

Then  retrieve the css in database and html as seperate variables.

after formatting the html variable with your  values, you then insert the css into it.

```
 example:
 var cssFile = your css from db
 var htmlFile = your formatted html string.
 var whereToInsert = htmlFile.IndexOf("<head>") +6;
 htmlfile = htmlFile.Insert(whereToInsert, cssFile)
```